# Serve media file from Django

Tags: django, apache, media

I know that it's not a good way to serve directly file and picture from django via views and urls dispatch, but if these files and pictures are served via the server (Apache), the whole world can see them. What if some files and pictures are private for the user, and only the connected user can see these files or pictures? In this case, I need to serve by django itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve private documents, you should use a Python view that does the security checks.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-documents/blob/master/documents/views.py).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache with mod_wsgi then you can use [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)

You are essentially looking to run the authorisation for some resources via Django, pass a header back to Apache saying 'Hey dude, lighten up. This user is okay to access this' Apache will then handle returning the resource.

Rough steps (as in, rough enough that you will need to do a little more research using the links I provide as a starting point)

Apache needs to know which resources are public and which aren't. Create a sub directory under media for both of these types (Why not go crazxy and call them /media/public/ and /media/private/)

Set up an alias for the public directory and a WSGIScriptAlias for the protected dir, the protected alias will be pointing to your main site handler (probably django.wsgi)

Add settings to vhost: 
`XSendFile On
 XSendFileAllowAbove On`

Add an urlconf to your Django app that handles /media/protected/{whatever} and routes it through your auth Django app auth logic. An example of this is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/django-users/tM6uGVbgA-U/DhJ7QeI9XPEJ)

A useful snippet for the above is [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2728/)
and another example for good measure [here](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/5796/restrict-downloading-of-files-to-authenticated-django-users-only)